# Can I prohibit summernote to inherit a CSS class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, summernote

I'm making a form using a purchased theme with bootstrap 3. The forms I like from the theme use a CSS class called ".smart-form *" which affects everything inside the form where it's being used. I'm also using Summernote inside the form and, as shown in the picture below, everything seems ok:

[image: Part of the form with Summernote]

The problem comes when opening the image or link attachment modal window. Here's a picture of the class:

[image: super form class]

And here's a picture of how the modal looks:

[image: broken modal window]

Now, if I uncheck those 3 attributes from that class, I get a perfect modal window but the rest of the form gets broken. Here's the correct modal window:

[image]

Is there any way of telling Summernote NOT to inherit those 3 CSS attributes?

Thanks!!!

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. 

What you have to do is "override" those settings specifically for the modal. You can do this by being more specific than the CSS you're overriding.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't find summernote's original specific attributes to override those. That's why I was wondering if I can't stop that class from passing to summernote.

Comment: You'll need to experiment with using `!important` to re-instate the attributes you want to keep on the modal's class.